# create sql database from sql express database

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-membership

I am working on asp.net membership website. I created the membership provider automatically, and now its stored in sql express database within the solution. I want to move all the tables to sql database instead of sql express. Last night I attached the sql express database to the sql server management studio, and I was able to see all the objects. Then, I run my solution in visual studio, and I got error: LOGIN FAILED for the sql express database, and the solution wasn't running. 
I have two questions. 
1. Why is that happening?
2. If I create the same database in sql server with the same objects, and then point to the sql server database instead of sql express database, will I have problems with the membershop provider?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting LOGIN FAILED when connecting to the new database or when the user is logging into your site

Comment: I am getting login failed when I am running the asp.net application and I am trying to open connection to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've moved a database from one host (running SQL Server Express) to another host (running a non-Express SKU). Is this correct?

Ensure that your membership connection string is pointing to the *new location* of the membership (the non-Express SQL Server). Ensure the logins and users are setup properly in the new SQL Server instance, as expected.

Comment: does attaching to the sql server management studio means moving? Because I just attached to create few more tables and SP.

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what steps you took to "attach"?

Comment: I opened SSMS right click on the database folder -> attach database, and I selected the database from the app_data folder in my asp.net application, then I created few tables, some stored procedures and I run the asp.net application again and I got the error message: login failed for my windows user. I am using windows authentication. All that is done locally, nothing is remotely. Thanks for your help

Comment: @laziale - same as p.campbell said: open up your web.config file and check the connection string, see what database it's pointing too.  Sounds like you moved the database but didn't updated the connection string.

Answer (score 1):

Attaching a database to a new server does not automatically create the necessary logins.

run `exec sp_change_users_login  'Report'` from within SSMS on your database.

If it comes back with anything in the result set, you'll need to run `exec sp_change_users_login 'Auto_Fix', '<username>'`

where  is the username from the first result set.